# Clusters available for using Hadoop/MapReduce framework

Tags: mapreduce, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

Does anyone know any free accessible clusters that are open to public and that use a Hadoop/MapReduce framework? There are plenty of tutorials of how to use MapReduce, but is there a way to test the examples without using my local single machine and installing the required framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon EC2 has ready to use Hadoop cluster for per time rent, not very expensive even for play. Other way is to play with Cloudera Hadoop VM http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/virtual-machine/. You can run cluster on several virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

I will soon have a solution - it's not free, but it is VERY cheap.

I have built a small cluster for training and education (via web access) and will be live in May 2013. 
I will rent out 4 node cluster for $2 a day or $10 a week.

Since the cluster is not very big, it will handle data sets of only 20-40GB, but will have full web access to run mapreduce, pig scripts.

Whilst I am asking for some money, it's not really a business - just hoping that I can pay the power bills!

http://jyrocluster.com

Regards,
Serge

Comment: Looks interesting serge.  One thing that might be an idea though is to offer data storage as well so once your ticket expires you can choose to keep the data for a fee per day with pre-payment (of course I don't mean in the cluster get shunted out onto cheap storage).  I am thinking of developers here with slower connections but need to test gb's of data.  Also keep in mind https://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/ as well for the .NET users

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Initially I did not want to offer data storage as I have limited space, and not a 'five nines' level of uptime....My plans were to add data storage, bigger nodes and HBase support...fingers crossed

Comment: BTW, almost ready to go live, so testing to complete and things to check...

Comment: Having some hiccups with Cloudera Manager, which will delay things a bit....;-(

Comment: the BETA is live - free access for all during BETA http://www.jyrocluster.com

Comment: Link not available anymore

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Apache Whirr](http://incubator.apache.org/whirr/) to deploy your own test cluster on Amazon EC2. This gives you more control than Elastic Map Reduce. It should be cheap if you are using it only to test map reduce jobs for short periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [CloudxLab](https://cloudxlab.com) a try. Though it is not free, it is quite affordable. It provides a complete environment to practice Hadoop, Spark, Kafka, Hive, Pig, HBase, Oozie, Zookeeper, Flume, Sqoop, Mahout, R, Linux, Python, Scala, NumPy, Scipy, scikit-learn etc. You will not have to install or configure any software on your local machine to use CloudxLab. Many of the popular trainers are already using CloudxLab.